# Can I connect an IR sensor to my android phone?

Tags: android, usb, sensors, digital, infrared

Is there any way to connect sensors to the Android? I want to connect an infrared sensor to my android phone (version 2,2) so that I can control my phone with an IR remote control. Apparently reading signals from the USB port is pretty much impossible, any other 
options?

Answer (score 1):

use IOIO Board which provides android adb host driver.so that u can connect you phone with as usb Device . IOIO boards gives u adc,io,i2c,spi etc. which u can access using IOIO library with android sdk. just search  "IOIO for android " in google .

Answer (score 0):

This device in beta at the moment its targeted at the universal remote market
 http://thinkflood.com/
I am looking for an ir receiver too and have sent an enquiry in. there its no developer info on the site, but the device can learn remote codes which, reading between the lines would imply it is a receiver as well as a transmitter.
I hope that this helps. If I make further progress I will let you know.